# How to change background color of table head(thead) and text color in `antd` table?

Tags: css, antd, ant-design-pro

Please explain me how to change background color of table head(thead) and text color in `antd` table (antd ui library)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change header colour by overriding table header class
(you will get all the element classes from developer tool)
for header class

```
.ant-table-thead>tr>th{
   background:#fdfdfd
}
```

as a result it will override the color globally
to override the color for specific table only just wrap the table in some div by giving class "test"
and override the css

```
.test .ant-table-thead>tr>th{
   background:#fdfdfd
}
```

and it will update the color for specific table head only

same for the text color as well.

```
.ant-table-row{
color:red
}
```

Comment: i fixed it! you explained it in a detailed way and easy to understand! thank you @Siddharth Bagal

Comment: expect some api